# Code indentation program giving Valgrind errors, can't figure out why

Tags: c, debugging, memory-leaks, malloc, valgrind

I'm working on a MOOC assignment and have run into a serious roadblock. The purpose of this function is to take a string that represents some code, and a "pad" string, and return a string that is the correctly indented version of the input code, using "pad" as the indent.

I keep getting Valgrind errors and, apparently, different output (the output they show for the error example is identical to mine *shrug*). I've looked through all the posts on similar Valgrind errors but have come up empty handed on figuring out what exactly is going wrong. Included below is the function, and the Valgrind errors.

**C code:**

```
/* Indent the C-code at memory block <indent>. String <pad> represents
 * one block of indentation. Only opening curly braces '{' increase the
 * indentation level, and closing curly braces '}' decrease the indentation level.
 * Return the pointer to the code after modification.
 * Calling code is responsible of freeing only the memory block returned by
 * the function.
 */
char *indent(char *input, const char *pad)
{
    // First, find number of pads to add (for malloc precision)
    unsigned int num_pads = 0;
    unsigned int level = 0;
    char *scan = input;

    while (*scan) {
        if (*scan == '{') {
            level++;
        }
        if (*scan == '}') {
            level -= (level) ? 1 : 0;
            num_pads--;
        }
        if (*scan == '\n') {
            num_pads += level;
        }
        scan++;
    }

    // Then, add the pads
    unsigned int pad_size = strlen(pad);
    unsigned int new_buffsize = strlen(input) + 1 + (num_pads * pad_size);

    char *out_buff = malloc(new_buffsize + 1);  // Address is 0 bytes after a block size of -- alloc'd
    level = 0;

    char* read_head = input;
    char* write_head = out_buff;

    while (*read_head) {
        *write_head = *read_head;   // Invalid write of size 1
        if (*read_head == '{') {
            level++;
        }
        if (*read_head == '}') {
            write_head -= (level) ? pad_size : 0;
            level -= (level) ? 1 : 0;
            *write_head = *read_head;
        }

        write_head++;
        if (*read_head == '\n') {

            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
                strncpy(write_head, pad, pad_size);   // Invalid write of size 1 [fixed maybe]
                write_head += pad_size;
            }
        }
        read_head++;

    }

    *write_head = '\0';

    free(input);
    return out_buff;
}
```

**Valgrind:**

```
==13133== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==13133== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==13133== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==13133== Command: ./main
==13133==
-- Original:
// This is a test file
int main(void) {
    /* comment
     block */
    printf("juu\n");
    while (1)
    {
        // Another comment
        while (2) {
            printf("jaa\n");
        }
    }
}
-- Comments removed:
int main(void) {

    printf("juu\n");
    while (1)
    {
        while (2) {
            printf("jaa\n");
        }
    }
}
==13133== Invalid write of size 1
==13133==    at 0x100000D4C: indent (polisher.c:205)
==13133==    by 0x100000904: main (main.c:20)
==13133==  Address 0x100a7d764 is 0 bytes after a block of size 132 alloc'd
==13133==    at 0x100008EBB: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.11.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==13133==    by 0x100000D11: indent (polisher.c:197)
==13133==    by 0x100000904: main (main.c:20)
==13133==
-- After indenting:
int main(void) {

    printf("juu\n");
    while (1)
    {
        while (2) {
            printf("jaa\n");
        }
    }
}
==13133==
==13133== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13133==     in use at exit: 26,466 bytes in 190 blocks
==13133==   total heap usage: 273 allocs, 83 frees, 37,049 bytes allocated
==13133==
==13133== 2,064 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 56 of 62
==13133==    at 0x10000917C: malloc_zone_malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.11.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==13133==    by 0x1004F9EFD: _objc_copyClassNamesForImage (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==13133==    by 0x1004ED182: protocols() (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==13133==    by 0x1004ED093: readClass(objc_class*, bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==13133==    by 0x1004EAC13: gc_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==13133==    by 0x1004F224E: objc_initializeClassPair_internal(objc_class*, char const*, objc_class*, objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==13133==    by 0x1004FF132: layout_string_create (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==13133==    by 0x1004ED83C: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==13133==    by 0x1004ED300: copySwiftV1MangledName(char const*, bool) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==13133==    by 0x1004ED2E9: copySwiftV1MangledName(char const*, bool) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==13133==    by 0x1004ED2E9: copySwiftV1MangledName(char const*, bool) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==13133==    by 0x1004ED2E9: copySwiftV1MangledName(char const*, bool) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==13133==
==13133== LEAK SUMMARY:
==13133==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13133==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13133==      possibly lost: 2,064 bytes in 1 blocks
==13133==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13133==         suppressed: 24,402 bytes in 189 blocks
==13133==
==13133== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==13133== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 16 from 16)
```

Thanks in advance for taking a look! I've been hitting my head against this for a while now.

Comment: Why do you `free(input);` which was a function argument?

Comment: The `Invalid write` errors tell you that you are attempting to write outside of the allocated buffer.  check your calculations.

Comment: Print the values that you computed for `num_pads` and `new_buffsize`. Put a counter in the code to keep track of how many bytes are actually written into the buffer.

Comment: `new_buffsize` given to `malloc` is calculated from `num_pads`, not `level`, which is only indirectly related. But `level` is used as a loop control to extend the string in the buffer allocated.

Comment: Checking the calculations now. Any thoughts about the "possibly lost" in this case?

Comment: You are leaking some memory. As @WeatherVane have pointed, you are freeing some memory which was not allocated, but allocating without freeing some other.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm freeing input, which was allocated before being passed into the function.

Comment: Corrected my calculations, so now it's just the "possibly lost." error. I don't see why freeing input would be a problem.

Comment: That `while(*scan)` loop isn't correctly working with edge cases, btw: Run it on `void foo(void) { int a; }` (all on one line)

Comment: when posting a question about code that does not work, always post code that cleanly compiles, including the `#include` statements and a `main()` function.

Comment: a call to `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, not a `unsigned int`.  so this kind of line: `unsigned int pad_size = strlen(pad);` should be: `size_t pad_size = strlen(pad);`